# How should I handle errors in ex scripts without waiting for user input?

Tags: vim, vi, ex

I'm trying to perform a search/replace with an ex script (targeting vim's ex implementation), as so:

```
ex -qc 'g/^[#][[:space:]]*$/d|x' file.txt
```

However, when `file.txt` already contains no matching content, the script hangs; when run without `-q`, it additionally displays the error below:

```
E486: Pattern not found: ^[#][[:space:]]*$
```

How can I build this script to continue (or, better, abort and immediately exit) on failure, rather than awaiting user input?

I'm using `ex` in favor of `sed -i` due to portability constraints (in-place edit support being a GNU extension to sed, and not available on all platforms).

Comment: You could try to perform a substitution on the entire line instead of `d`. It would allow you to use the `/e` flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send vim a separate quit command with `-c 'q'`, which it will execute after the search/replace (works on my vim version `7.3.315`):

```
ex -c 'g/^[#][[:space:]]*$/d|x' -c 'q' file.txt
```

Also note `ex` appears to execute the commands in the order which they appear in ARGV, so:

```
ex -c 'q' -c 'g/^[#][[:space:]]*$/d|x' file.txt
```

Quits before doing the search/replace.